# Missing jspweb.xml error

Tags: jsp, maven, tomcat7, precompile

I assume that since jspweb.xml is missing that my plugin did not compile my jsp pages.  How to make this compile it?  Am I missing a setup?  Here is my pom snippet on jspc:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jspc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- Use the Tomcat 6 JSP compiler -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>${basedir}/target/jspweb.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.4c</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```